# How to get local hour from moment.js

Tags: javascript, internationalization, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to display differents date and times using

```
moment().format('llll');
```

It provide result like that in english

> Tue, Oct 21, 2014 1:11 PM

and like that in french

> mar. 21 oct. 2014 13:11

But I want to display only time (1:11PM or 13:11) and not the full date. 
How can I do that ?

EDIT: The perfect thing would be to display seconds
1:11:15 pm and 13:11:15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only the localized time, in moment.js you have the 'LT' formatter:

```
moment().format('LT');
```

the result is the localized time :

```
1:11PM
```

Unfortunately, it seems that there are no formatters for localized time displaying seconds.

Comment: As of moment version 2.8.4 there's a formatter "LTS" which also displays the seconds. See the docs here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/